# checking condition for two different breed of agents at once

Tags: netlogo

I have two agents mosquito and human. they both have different states like susceptible and infected.
I want to check states for my agents and do the action
I want to check if mosquito is infected and human susceptible then infect human and vice versa.
please help on the codes

```
to go
  ask human
  [
    set heading  random 360
    forward random 2
      
      ]
  **if any? human-here infected? true and any? mosquito-here infected? false
ask mosquito [ set infected? true
    set color red]
  tick** 
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to decide which agents you want to ask to take the action necessary to infect or be infected. For that, I suggest using the "with" primitive that allows you to create a subset of the agentsets for which it makes sense to check if they can be infected.
`humans with [susceptible? = true and infected? = false]`

After that you can ask this group to check for the conditions necessary to become infected themselves. `if any? mosquitos-here with [infected? = true] [set infected? true]`

I suggest doing this separately for both humans and mosquitos as your conditions might differ for both. Combined, your code could look something like this:

```
to go
  ask humans
  [
    set heading  random 360
    forward random 2
      ]
  
  ask mosquitos
  [
    set heading  random 360
    forward random 2
      ]  
  
  ask humans with [susceptible? = true and infected? = false] [
    if any? mosquitos-here with [infected? = true] [set infected? true set color red]
]
  
  ask mosquitos with [susceptible? = true and infected? = false] [
    if any? humans-here with [infected? = true] [set infected? true set color red]
]
  
  tick
end
```

If infection happens in a symmetric way, you could also use something like the following but I wouldn't suggest it since I assume you want some distinction between humans and mosquitos

```
  ask turtles with [susceptible? = true and infected? = false] [
    let my-breed breed
    if any? turtles-here with [infected? = true and breed != my-breed] [set infected? true set color red]
]
```